# do I have a 26 fork using 27.5 wheel?

Tags: wheels, fork

I realize I've been riding for a year using this configuration, I have a suntour sf13-xcm-ds-hlo-26-100 (which I think was designed for 26). Suntour website doesn't provide full info about the Fork, will I have a problem with the wheel or the fork?

Comment: A decimal sized 26" wheel has a 559mm rim.  A 27.5" wheel has a 584mm rim.  (A 29" (or 700c) wheel has a 622mm rim and a regular 27" wheel has a 630mm rim.)  The difference between 559 and 584 is only 25mm, and the difference in tire clearance is half that -- about 12mm or 0.47 inches.  So, tire widths being reasonably equal, you lose less than a half inch in clearance with the 27.5" tire.

Answer (score 4):

If the wheel fits.....

If you have been using it, then no, you won't have problems. Its not that uncommon for people to shoe horn a 27.5" wheel into a 26 fork or frame. just running a front wheel will slightly change the bikes geometry, but not enough to make a big difference.

Where you can run into trouble is if clearances are not enough and you ride in muddy conditions, causing build up and blocking.

When you replace the tire, you will need to be careful to get one that fits. Most 27.5" "upgrades" require a smallish (2.1) tire, and you will want to avoid ones with aggressive side lugs unless you can try before you buy.

Comment: Yep, this is the answer to many questions: *if it fits/works/etc* ...

Comment: One thing to be very careful of is tyre clearance at full compression. For instance the crown on the older 26" Fox 36 forks could hit a 27.5" tyre at full compression.

Comment: @OllyHodgson, sounds like an additional bottom-out protection. I wonder if such a hit would block the tire, resulting in a front slide-out.

Comment: @Vorac http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/article/trail-tech-five-reasons-not-to-convert-26in-to-650b-36241